# Add a separator between buttons in a menu bar (HTML/CSS)

Tags: css, menu

I'm making a mobile website and having some difficulty with making a few changes to my menu bar. I'm not an expert on this field so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the codes to the menu bar.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    * { padding: 0; margin: 3; }
    body { padding: 5px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width:95%; font-size:12px}
    ul { list-style: none; }
    ul li {
float: left;
padding: 1.5px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;}
ul a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 75%; height: 50px; text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#000; border-style: solid; border-width:2px; border-color:#1570a6; text-decoration: none; }
    ul a:hover {background-color:#5A87B4; }
```

HTML

```
<div> 
<ul>
<li>
  <div align="center"><a href="../Software.html" >Software</a>
    </div>
</li>
  <li>
    <div align="center"><a href="../Products.html">Products</a></div>
  </li>
<li>
<a href="../Order Online.html">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is a basic menu bar and i want to adjust this to the center and also have horozontal lines to break each button apart while all this is centered and fits a 100% on a mobile screen. All your help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: Its like having some space after each button but instead theres a horizontal line

EDIT: Changed the width from 75% to 80px. Note that i also changed the div ID of my code because i was having some other problems with identification. :) Hope this wont confuse you

```
#menubar * { padding: 0; margin: 2; }
    body { padding: 5px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width:95%; font-size:12px}

#menubar ul{text-align:center;}

#menubar ul li { display:inline-block; padding: 2px;  position: relative;  }

#menubar ul a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 80px; height: 50px; text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#000; border-style: solid; border-width:2px; border-color:#1570a6; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added below lines in your css code. I hope this is what you want.

```
ul{
   display:inline-block;
   overflow:hidden;
}

div{
  text-align:center;
}

li:after{
   border-right:50px solid black;
   content:"";
   position:relative;
   left:10px;
   top:-27px;  
   z-index:-1;
   display:block;
   height:1px;
}

li:last-child{
   margin-right:-14px
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPZ2T/1/)

Comment: Almost perfect. I need the lines to be horizontal not vertical. Could you please amend the code to that :)

Comment: @AntonFernando Sorry, that fiddle was not good. I updated my post again. please check.

Comment: Ok i used this and its working but i need a line on the left hand side as well to look evenly good all around. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with that with some extra code perhaps

Comment: Yes but i changed my menu bar code slightly so it doesnt work for me. Check the original post on where i changed. Changed the width of the menu buttons from 75% to 80px.

Comment: @AntonFernando I can't help like this. Please make a working fiddle, so that I can help you soon.

Comment: @AntonFernando Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/bkDHk/1/ and also this http://jsfiddle.net/bkDHk/2/

Comment: Theres too much of a gap in between the buttons, This is for a mobile website. So when i preview it the thrid button slides to the next bottom line which i cannot have. Could you somehow make the lines a bit shorter and still have them on both sides? :)

Comment: @AntonFernando increase the `margin-left` value in negative which is on `li`. The `li`'s will come close. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bkDHk/3/

Comment: The button on the left hand side moves out of the phone screen when i do that

Comment: @AntonFernando Thats not a big deal. Give `ul{margin-right:-15px;}` or a value on which you are satisfied.

Comment: margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-20px; } that was the closest i could get by trial and error to near perfection. I really appreciate everything you did and all the support you gave me mate :)

Comment: how do i reward people for helping if i cant give rep yet on this site

Comment: How do i do that. Sorry for the noob question. just a new member

Comment: Ill be asking a few more questions soon to get some rep and i will try and help out some other people as well :)

Comment: @AntonFernando ok very well :)

Answer (score 0):

from your current css remove `float:left;` on `li`'s and add `text-align:center;` and it should work:

```
ul li {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbcXL/).

#### Update

In that case you can change the CSS to.

```
ul li{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul li:before {
    content: " - ";
}

ul li:first-child:before {
    content: none;
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbcXL/1/)

Comment: That will make the menu buttons vertical. I want the menu to be horizontal as well :)

Comment: what do you mean by lines ?

Comment: A basic horizontal line like a <hr> but i want them next to each button on either side. Its like having some space between each button on a menu bar but instead of the space i want the horizontal line.

Comment: The line should be stretchable and change in size according to the screen size and i dont think the dash could do that :)

Comment: In that case why not manually add an image or the element you want after each <li> ??

Answer (score 0):

Now just **remove** `float:left` in your `li` and **add** `display:inline-block;` and **add** `text-align center` in your **ul** tag

as like this

```
ul{
text-align:center;
}

ul li{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
float:left; // remove this line
}
```

**[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/nA1rnN2p)**

Comment: That makes the background colour of the header in my webpage to appear behind my buttons even though theyre centered. Any way to get around that?